# Is there any google service provided for the storage and distribution of in app Products in android App?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on an android app with in App products . I have read about different services like in app billing,in app querying purchased items. I was wondering If there is any service which I could store my in app products and distribute (App could downnload from there) from that.I am new to in app products and want to know if this was possible . Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) to store some extra files that you can download it later on. Although it was not meant for this reason, but you might be able to store your in-app products in such expansion files and download it when needed (i.e. after purchase)

Answer (score 1):

Google simply acts as the payment processor and lets you know when a payment is made, cancelled, or fully processed. Any further action on the purchase must be done by you, and Google does not provide any server to host the in app content specially. All of that must be done on your own server.